# Workflow rule on User object, cannot access lookup field (Contact) details in email template

Tags: workflow, force.com-sites, contact, guest-user, user-registration

I am using custom portals.  The registration is done using standard salesforce functionality (code) like this.

```
userId = Site.createPortalUser(user, accountId, password, false);
```

The **false** here indicates that I turned off the email that will be sent after User registration.  So, instead I created a workflow rule and workflow email alert to be sent.  The email will be sent when a new User is created with specific profile.

The email is sent correctly to the user who has registered.  The email body has 'Contact.FirstName'.  Contact is the lookup field on User that is created using the above code.

The problem is this Contact.FirstName is not populated in the email.  Observed that even if we add User.Name, it is picking the Name of the default Guest User (of the custom portal) and not the user who is registering.

How to solve this?  I want to include the details of the user who registered.

EDIT:
Salesforce acknowledged that the problem exists and provided a solution which doesn't work at all.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SdBfAAK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I found for this is, instead of Workflow, I am sending singleMailMessage using apex.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this issue myself and found a solution.

I am also sending an email template using a workflow rule on the User object, but the User merge fields were picking up the Site Guest User instead).

The solution is to use the 'Workflow Target User' merge fields, e.g. {!Target_User.FirstName}. When using this merge field, the correct name of the user was used, not the Guest Site User.